# What is the correct SSRS to SSAS connection string format?

Tags: reporting-services, ssas-tabular, ssrs-2017

```
Data Source=my-server-01\\SQLSERVER2017;Catalog=Catalog=TabularProjectTest_serviceaccount1_ffcd154a-5c55-4f69-8a40-76628f97227f;
```

I'm using the above connection string in an SSRS visual studio project to connect to an SSAS tabular database with out any problem.

However, when i try to create the same connection string from SSRS report manager (web portal) and test connection, it fails with the following error.

```
ERROR: Report server dump occured. Exception: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. ---> System.ArgumentException: The connection string is not valid.
```

Any one know why this connection works in visual studio but fails when created from the SSRS web portal?

**RESOLVED**: All i had to do was to remove 1 back slash from the connection string, so now the below works.

```
    Data Source=my-server-01\SQLSERVER2017;Catalog=Catalog=TabularProjectTest_serviceaccount1_ffcd154a-5c55-4f69-8a40-76628f97227f;
```